# Watson pandas read csv titanic

Tags: pandas, csv, ibm-watson

I want to do Kaggle titanic competition in watson but unfortunately watson IBM Studio is unable to handle my request
Has somebody an idea why?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dN2CO.png)

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. It was general settings problem. https://dataplatform.cloud.ibm.com/docs/content/wsj/manage-data/add-data-project.html?context=analytics